# Add audio (with an offset) to video with FFMPEG

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg

I have a 10 minute video and a 50 minute audio mp3.
The video starts at 500 seconds into the audio.
Using FFMPEG, how can I add the the audio to the video but specify **a 500 seconds audio offset** (So that they sync up)?

**EDIT:**

Down the bottom of this [page](http://howto-pages.org/ffmpeg/#delay) it suggests how to specify an offset.

```
$ ffmpeg -i video_source -itsoffet delay -i audio_source -map 0:x -map 1:y .......
```

However, when I apply this, it still starts the audio from the start.

Answer (score 18):

We are 8 years later, and the `-itsoffset` does work.

Exactly as in [your linked page](http://howto-pages.org/ffmpeg/#delay):

```
ffmpeg -i input_1 -itsoffset 00:00:03 -i input_2
```

Note that you place the `-itsoffset` switch **before** the input you want to **delay**, in this case `input_2` will be delayed.

So in your case that the video starts later, you would add `-itsoffset 00:08:20` before the video input.

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't get audio to offset properly either, and some searching suggests that `-itsoffset` is currently [broken](https://web.archive.org/web/20130130012747/http://roundup.libav.org:80/issue359).

You could try and get/compile an old version of ffmpeg before it broke (which doesn't sound like much fun).

Alternately, you could pad your audio with the necessary silence using something like [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/) and then combine:

```
sox -null silence.mp3 trim 0 500    # use -r to adjust sample-rate if necessary
sox silence.mp3 input.mp3 padded_input.mp3
ffmpeg -i in.avi -i padded_input.mp3 out.avi
```