# Add multiple audio files to video at specific points using FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to create a video out of a sequence of images and various audio files using FFmpeg. While it is no problem to create a video containing the sequence of images with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg video.mpg
```

I haven't found a way yet to add audio files at specific points to the generated video. 
Is it possible to do something like:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -i image%d.jpg -i audio1.mp3 AT 10s -i audio2.mp3 AT 15s video.mpg
```

Any help is much appreciated!

EDIT:

The solution in my case was to use sox as suggested by blahdiblah in the answer below. You first have to create an empty audio file as a starting point like that:

```
sox -n -r 44100 -c 2 silence.wav trim 0.0 20.0
```

This generates a 20 sec empty WAV file. After that you can mix the empty file with other audio files.

```
sox -m silence.wav "|sox sound1.mp3 -p pad 0" "|sox sound2.mp3 -p pad 2" out.wav
```

The final audio file has a duration of 20 seconds and plays sound1.mp3 right at the beginning and sound2.mp3 after 2 seconds.
To combine the sequence of images with the audio file we can use FFmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -i video_%05d.png -i out.wav -r 25 out.mp4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7426179/85950) on adding a single audio input with some offset.  The [`-itsoffset` bug mentioned there](http://roundup.libav.org/issue359) is still open, but see users' comments for some cases in which it does work.

If it works in your case, that would be ideal:

```
ffmpeg -i in%d.jpg -itsoffset 10 -i audio1.mp3 -itsoffset 15 -i audio2.mp3 out.mpg
```

If not, you should be able to combine all the audio files with [sox](http://sox.sourceforge.net/sox.html), overlaying or inserting silence to produce the correct offsets and then use that as input to FFmpeg.  Not as convenient, but guaranteed to work.

Comment: Sounds promising, thank you! I will try this out as soon as possible.

Comment: It worked for me, rocking ffmpeg version 0.8.6-6:0.8.6-1~bpo60+1 (Debian 6).  I know, I know....

Comment: The bug link is broken and see [my new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7426179/add-audio-with-an-offset-to-video-with-ffmpeg/56403352#56403352) at the linked question, the `-itsoffset` switch does work if used correctly.

Answer (score 1):

One approach I can think of is to create your audio file for the whole duration of the video first and then mux the audio with the video file

Comment: And how would you create the audio file with ffmpeg? I can not create the audio file first manually as there are too many combinations possible.

Comment: but then they are simply concatenated. as mentioned in the question i have to add the audio files at a specific point in the timeline

Comment: as mentioned in the above answer use audacity or sox to generate the audio file by inserting silence segments as and when needed.

Answer (score 0):

The command from the chosen answer did not work in my case. So, I followed the advice given in both answers of blahdiblah and d33pika.

Let's say we have silent video *input.mp4* and two audio files *1.mp3* and *2.mp3*. The duration of the video is 20 seconds. The duration of audio files is unknown but they are about 2-5 seconds. First must be inserted at sec 3 of the video and second at sec 12.

The solution, generally, is to create silent mp3, concat it with given mp3 files, and then mux resulted audio with video.

First, we need to know the duration of 1.mp3

```
ffprobe -v error -show_entries format=duration -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 1.mp3
```

The above command returned `3.5` as a result.

Now we can calculate the duration of silent audio: `12 - (3 + 3.5) = 5.5` sec.

Then, generate silent mp3:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=r=24000:cl=mono -t 5.5 -q:a 9 -acodec libmp3lame silent.mp3
```

Note, that my 1.mp3 and 2.mp3 are mono with bitrate 24000, so we created silent.mp3 the same.

Now we can concat files:

```
ffmpeg -i "concat:1.mp3|silent.mp3|2.mp3" -c copy result.mp3
```

And, finally, add the result.mp3 to the video:

```
ffmpeg -y -i input.mp4 -itsoffset 00:00:03.000 -i result.mp3 -map 0:0 -map 1:0 -c:v copy -preset ultrafast -async 1 output.mp4
```

A bit complicated, and I am still looking for a way to add audio files with one command.